# How to round numbers in octave

Tags: rounding, octave

My input is `96682.35699908705` and I have to round it to `97000`.

What function should I use to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide it by 1000 so it becomes `96.68235699908705`, round it using `round(x)` or `roundb(x)`, then multiply it by 1000 again

`round` and `roundb` are explained [in the octave documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Utility-Functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
round(96682.35699908705/power(10,3))*power(10,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `x = 96682.35699908705`, then you can try

```
p = floor(log10(x))-1;
r = round(x/10^p)*10^p
```

which gives

```
>> r = round(x/10^p)*10^p
r =  97000
```